# How to interpret the OEIS function for the "even fractal sequence" A103391 (1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, ...)

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractals

I'm interested in a particular integer sequence that is the same as itself when you remove all of the even-indexed members of the sequence. It begins (1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5, ...). I looked it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, and it is A103391—it's page is here: https://oeis.org/A103391.

I'm having trouble interpreting the formula given for the sequence on that page by Johannes W. Meijer. First I'll just paste it as it is on the page:

```
a((2*n-3)*2^p+1) = n, p >= 0 and n >= 2, with a(1) = 1
```

I'm interpreting this to be:
$$
a\left(\left(2n-3\right)2^{p+1}\right)=n
$$
with the associated conditions.

On it's face, the equation doesn't make sense to me, and I'm assuming there's either some sort of OEIS shorthand or convention for sequence description that I'm missing. I'm assuming that $n$ is the $n$th interger in the sequence, but I'm not sure what $p$ would be. And anyway, it seems to generate nonsense, such as, if $n=3$:
$$
3*2^{p+1}=3
$$
which would require $p$ to be $-1$, which is outside the range. If the equation is in fact
$$
a\left(\left(2n-3\right)2^p+1\right)=n
$$
Then it's even worse because, at $n=3$:
$$
3*2^p+1=3\\
2^p=\frac23\\
p=\log_2\frac23\\
p\approx-.58
$$
which is both outside the bound and non-integral. I imagine I'm missing something really stupid, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Comment: You wrote $3\cdot2^p+1=3$, but the formula actually gives $a(3\cdot2^p+1)=3$. That's why your calculation is getting nonsensical answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is the second interpretation: $a((2n-3)2^p+1)=n$. Here plugging in $n$ does not mean finding the $n$th element of the sequence; instead, it's telling you all the places in the sequence where the value is $n$. For example, when $n=4$, the formula tells you that $a(5\cdot 2^p+1)=4$ for any $p\ge0$. Indeed, $4=a(6)=a(11)=a(21)=a(41)=a(81)=\cdots$.

If you want to calculate $a(m)$ for some odd $m$ using this formula, you need to write $m$ in the form $(2n-3)2^p+1$ for some $p\ge0$ and $n\ge2$. To do so, simply divide $m-1$ by $2$ repeatedly until you reach an odd number $k$, and then set $n=(k+3)/2$. For example, to calculate $a(2017)$, we keep halving $2016\to1008\to504\to252\to126\to63$, whence $a(2017)=n=(63+3)/2=33$.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew I was going to feel stupid. Quick follow up question, is this a standard way to define a series via formula? Should I have known that a(x) means the value at the $x$th position? For instance, in my own playing around with the sequence I saw that I could show that the nth member of the sequence was:
$$
f(n) = 
\cases{
f\left(n+1 \above .25pt 2\right) & \text{if } n\in2\mathbb N+1\cr
n+2 \above .25pt 2 & \text{if } n\in2\mathbb N
}
$$
Is that an improper way to define it?

Comment: $a(x)$ is pretty unambigously the value of $a$ at the $x$th position. Your recursive formula is perfectly valid too (as long as you add some initial values, such as $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Just to clarify, I definitely see why I need to define $f(1)$, but I think $f(2)$ is covered by the formula, right? So I could say, for all $n\ge1$:
$$
f(n) = 
\cases{
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
f\left(n+1 \above .25pt 2\right) & \text{if } n\in2\mathbb N+1\\
n+2 \above .25pt 2 & \text{if } n\in2\mathbb N\\
}
$$

Comment: Oh right, I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

By order of operations, `a((2*n-3)*2^p+1)` means $a((((2\times n)-3) \times 2^p)+1) = a(2^{p}(2n-3)+1)$.

For example, let $n = 4$ and $p = 1$, then $$
a(2^{1}(\underbrace{2 \times 4 -3}_5)+1) = a(11) = 4.
$$

We can let $p$ be any non-negative integer.